# How to HTTP post from Powerpoint

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint file, with only a textbox per slide.

During the presentation, how can I send an HTTP GET/POST request to a web server, containing

- either the number of the current slide
- or (even better) the text of the textbox of the current slide?

A **new HTTP request should be sent whenever the presented slide changes.**

Comment: Have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679171/make-a-powerpoint-pdf-to-call-back-home

Comment: Thanks Steve - actually, viewing in presentation/slide show mode and enabled macros can be ensured/assumed. But, how would I access the slide number or (preferably) the textbox-text, and send it via HTTP?

Comment: That would depend; how do you expect this action to be triggered?  User clicks a shape on the slide (ie, a Next/Previous button)?  Or automatically, somehow?  That gets trickier.

Comment: Each HTTP request should be sent whenever the presented slide changes (the user changes the slides manually with the keyboard, no automatically timed slide changes).