# Make a Powerpoint \ PDF to call back home

Tags: http, get, powerpoint

I am Trying to track openings of Powerpoint Documents (ppt \ pptx). i'm looking for a way to make the ppt make  some kind of a HTTP GET request for an image of a css file, making t possible to track those requests.
is there any way i could make the powerpoint client make an internet request on openeing of a ppt \ pptx object?

also - same question for PDF files (if i am supposed to post a different question, let me know)

(there are ways to make this thing with doc and xls)

** Hope this one is not off topic.

Comment: Unlike Word/Excel, PowerPoint will not run code automatically when you open a presentation.  If you can be sure the user will open it in slide show view (save as PPSX, though this isn't foolproof) and are certain that they won't have macro security set to a level that disables VBA, you could do this in VBA.  Or if you can have the user install an add-in, that could trap the event that occurs when PPT opens a presentation and run some code (but not on Macs).

Comment: Thanks Steve!, I am trying to do this with VBA but cannot make an HTTP request, also, could not find a way to do this "on-loading" of the presentation but only on button \ image click. could you please help me on there issues?

Comment: You might want to start a separate question about making HTTP requests in VB/VBA.  More people will see it, you'll have better odds of getting an answer.  As I mentioned, PPT will not run code on load of a presentation unless you create and install an addin.  There's a sort of workaround that I explain on my FAQ site here:
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00741_How_can_I_get_my_code_to_run_automatically_when_a_presentation_opens-.htm

Comment: you are right, here is a link to the new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744395/making-simple-http-get-request-on-vba

thanks again!